# Назначение клавишь в mac os

Tags: mac

Стал счастливым обладателем Макбука....
На виноусе пользовался програмуленой keyremapper, много занимаюсь копи пастом
Итого назначил контрл+С на f1, контрл+V на f2
обнаружил на маке кучу не нужных мне кнопок)
Как можно назначить допустим на control комбинацию comand+c?
перебрал много ремаперов, но они не умеют назначать комбинацию клавишь
Уверен что можно както решить, помогите!!

Comment: Это все делается из стандартной настройки клавиатуры https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271/mac какие, блин, еще ремаперы?

Comment: @DiD подскажите, как там глобально в системе назначить чтоб по F1 делалась команда Cmd-C?

Comment: я создаю новую комбинацию, как ее называть? и как ее назначить на клавишу допустим control или f1

Comment: там можно создать комбинации на пункты меню, пишете их название

Comment: Я вам советую прежде чем решать такого рода задачи - изучить мануал по MacOS. или посмотреть серию видео о стандартных возможностях MacOS. Возможно, тогда у вас не будут на такие проблемы как горячие клавиши уходить время.

Comment: @СергейЧумаков возможно вам нужно использовать appleScript [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57361208/14255891). Тоже стандартные возможности MacOS.